# what does this `context_.Reset` do in v8 runtime implemation of react-native js-runtime?

Tags: c++, react-native, v8

I m a noob in c++ and v8 engine. when I check the source code of the implementation of v8 JSI, I found which I can not understand: Here is the constructor of the v8 runtime: (pls see comments line below)

```js
V8Runtime::V8Runtime(const std::string &timezoneId) {
  if (!s_platform) {
    s_platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializeICU();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(s_platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();
  }

  arrayBufferAllocator_.reset(
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator());
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams createParams;
  createParams.array_buffer_allocator = arrayBufferAllocator_.get();
  isolate_ = v8::Isolate::New(createParams);
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
  if (!timezoneId.empty()) {
    isolate_->DateTimeConfigurationChangeNotification(
        v8::Isolate::TimeZoneDetection::kCustom, timezoneId.c_str());
  }
#endif
  isolate_->Enter();
  v8::HandleScope scopedIsolate(isolate_);
  context_.Reset(isolate_, CreateGlobalContext(isolate_)); 
//what does this reset for? why I need to reset the context just after I create the global context of it?
  context_.Get(isolate_)->Enter();
}
```

Below is the code of `CreateGlobalContext`:

```cpp
v8::Local<v8::Context> V8Runtime::CreateGlobalContext(v8::Isolate *isolate) {
  v8::HandleScope scopedIsolate(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate_);
  global->Set(
      v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "_v8runtime", v8::NewStringType::kNormal)
          .ToLocalChecked(),
      v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, V8Runtime::GetRuntimeInfo));
  return v8::Context::New(isolate_, nullptr, global);
}
```

repo's origin is [here](https://github.com/Kudo/react-native-v8/blob/master/src/v8runtime/V8Runtime.cpp), a v8 implementation of react-native js-runtime.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is probably just defensive programming. Just treat it as an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context_` is a global handle (`v8::Global`), its `Reset(...)` method is how you assign to the pointer it wraps. So it's being "reset" from being uninitialized to storing the newly created global context here.

> This is probably just defensive programming. – Botje

No, defensive programming has nothing to do with it.

> Just treat it as an assignment. – Botje

Yes. If `context_` was a `v8::Local` (which would be a problem for other reasons), then you'd just see `context_ = CreateGlobalContext(...)` here.